# Eclipse: How to implement a ViewPart to show source code?

Tags: eclipse, view, eclipse-plugin, declaration

I'm implementing an Eclipse plugin which has to show source code on a view. I want to show the source code snippet on a view such as the Declaration View (in particular, with text highlighting).

- Which viewer and labelProvider do I have to use?
- How to highlight text?

Comment: This is how I managed to do it:

<code>


  JavaTextTools javaTextTools = JavaPlugin.getDefault().getJavaTextTools();

  IPreferenceStore combinedPreferenceStore = plugin.getCombinedPreferenceStore();

  final JavaSourceViewerConfiguration configuration = new JavaSourceViewerConfiguration(
    javaTextTools.getColorManager(), combinedPreferenceStore, null, null );
viewer = new SourceViewer( container, null, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL );
  viewer.configure( configuration );
final Font font = JFaceResources.getFont( JFaceResources.TEXT_FONT );
viewer.getTextWidget().setFont( font );
</code>